# TSQL query for Week Comparison

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a table that has a TASK_START_DATE and TASK_FINISH_DATE Columns of type datetime

I need help with a query that returns all Tasks when the Task: (date = just the date - I think I can do a conversion to the date from datetime on SQL 2008R2, it works fine)


- is within 2 weeks previous of the current date or two weeks after the current date.

Similarly I also need the records whose TaskEnd values are within 2 weeks previous or two weeks before

I've been trying things like which would get tasks where the start date is within the two previous weeks, but I have to do the same for TASK_FINISH_DATE and I think my and's and or's are all jumbled up, any help is appreciated.

```
Convert(Date, TASK_START_DATE) <=  Convert(Date, DateAdd(ww, -2, GetDate()))
```

Short version:
How do I correctly write a query that combines all records with the TASK_START_DATE **OR** TASK_END_DATE within two weeks in the future or past, i.e.

```
Select Task_ID, TASK_NAME, TASK_START_DATE, TASK_END_DATE
where 
???
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add days to your date for comparision:

```
Select * from Table
Where column between getdate()-14 and getdate()+14
```

Comment: Didn't think that SQL implicitly converted the DT to a numeric to allow the add (is it converting to float maybe?), but you learn something new every day! Good tip - I'd been using dateadd(d, 1, xxx)

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to use "Convert" function. "GetDate" function returns datetime value and your columns' types are datetime. You can add day number directly like this:

```
Select * from Table
Where (TASK_START_DATE between getdate() - 14 and getdate() + 14)
or (TASK_FINISH_DATE between getdate() - 14 and getdate() + 14)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can declare variables or have the comparison dates right in the where clause. I use GETDATE() to get the date/time for right now as it returns a DATETIME object. Then I use DATEADD to adjust it for days, months, years, etc, and then you have to convert it to a DATE before sticking it in a variable of type DATE. Note in the [DATEADD](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819.aspx) method I pass in the adjustment type (D = days), then adjust it + or - 14 days.

Alternatively you could just use 14 days ago to the minute if you don't do the DATE conversions...you'd have to remove the converts from the variable declarations as well as the where clause. Depends on the results you want though.

```
DECLARE @twoWeeksAgo DATE = CONVERT(DATE, DATEADD(D, -14, GETDATE()));
DECLARE @twoWeeksAhead DATE = CONVERT(DATE, DATEADD(D, 14, GETDATE()));

SELECT 
    Task_ID, 
    TASK_NAME, 
    TASK_START_DATE, 
    TASK_END_DATE
FROM
    TABLE
WHERE 
    CONVERT(DATE, TASK_START_DATE) BETWEEN @twoWeeksAgo AND @twoWeeksAhead
    OR CONVERT(DATE, TASK_END_DATE) BETWEEN @twoWeeksAgo AND @twoWeeksAhead
```

Also note that the BETWEEN operator in the WHERE clause is inclusive, meaning it will include records where the TASK_START_DATE is equal to the dates held by the variables. If you wanted to exclude records with the same value as @twoWeeksAhead, for example, you would have to use something like

```
WHERE 
    (CONVERT(DATE, TASK_START_DATE) >= @twoWeeksAgo 
        AND CONVERT(DATE, TASK_START_DATE) < @twoWeeksAhead)
    OR (CONVERT(DATE, TASK_END_DATE) >= @twoWeeksAgo 
        AND CONVERT(DATE, TASK_END_DATE) < @twoWeeksAhead)
```